# wp_localize_script not working with jquery handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to spoof the jquery handle as I use grunt / bower in my WP projects to create concatenated minified builds of all my plugins and scripts.  I'd like to include jQuery 2.1.3 within this, and dequeue the older version of jquery that ships with wordpress, but in order to make sure other plugins work I thought to (maybe in a bit of a hacky way) use the jquery handle for my script.

Unfortunately it seems like localize script wont fire though.  What I'm doing is this :

```
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 

    wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/public/js/all.min.js', array(), false, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    $localize_data = array(
    ....all the stuff I need in my scripts....
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'nona', $localize_data );
```

This is obviously wrapped in a function thats called on the appropriate hook, it works with a custom handle, but then there are compatibility issues, any ideas other than just creating an a array and converting it to a javascript object manually?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: note I've looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127030/wp-localize-script-with-handle-jquery-wordpress-script which doesn't provide a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The function `wp_localize_script` calls [`wp_scripts()->localize`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php#L154), and at the top of [that function](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php#L191) there is this:

```
if ( $handle === 'jquery' )
    $handle = 'jquery-core';
```

It changes the *handle* to `jquery-core`, so going to see where the [default scripts are registered](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L50) we find that `jquery` doesn't reference the javascript file directly but via the dependencies `jquery-core` and `jquery-migrate`:

```
// jQuery
$scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate' ), '1.11.2' );
$scripts->add( 'jquery-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.11.2' );
$scripts->add( 'jquery-migrate', "/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate$suffix.js", array(), '1.2.1' );
```

I would try to change the *handle* to `jquery-core`, something like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_localized', 1);

function jquery_localized() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery-core');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-core', get_template_directory_uri().'/public/js/all.min.js', array(), false, true );

    $localize_data = array(
    // ....all the stuff I need in my scripts....
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'jquery-core', 'nona', $localize_data );

    // this for compatibility purpose
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core' ), false, true );
}
```

Note that I added `1` as priority to execute this function before others on the same hook.

Comment: Hey, this get the vars out but doesn't seem to work for jQuery deps ?

Comment: sure -, basically plugins that rely on jQuery are bugging out  with the error jquery is not defined, and when looking at the load order they load before my script no matter what i try.

Comment: I've update my answer adding the priority to the hook function

Comment: hey have you tested this? I tried altering the priority before with no joy.

Comment: yes I've tested it and it seemed to work. could you provide some plugins name that have this problem?

Comment: Debug bar was the first one.  Funnily enough.  had a look at the plugin code and they're not anything that I imagine they shouldn't, just concerned about supporting plugins that do it the right way.